# How do I get all views on a page that have a given class?

Tags: nativescript

I don't see any `getViewsByClass()` equivalent to `getViewById()`.   Any thoughts on the best way to determine all views on a page that have a particular class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this plugin https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-dom/blob/master/README.md it has a utility method for what you want, since you are correct nothing in the core exposed for that.